# Is there a way to prevent some files from appearing on the main branch in the remote repo?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm working on a simple project with other people. They use Eclipse to build it, but I don't like Eclipse and wrote a makefile and some batch/bash scripts to do the job for me.

I want to keep track of changes I make to these files, but I don't want others to see them in the main repo (at least not on the default branch, it would be okay to have my own). I could make a subrepo, but I don't want to type the folder each time I build something (besides, keeping makefile NOT in the root would be a bit awkward).

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use MQ-extension
- Have adding these needed (personal local) files in MQ-patch(es)
- Work locally with patch applied, unapply patch before push

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty convenient. For future readers - remember to `hg qcommit`.